# iOS remote xml is parsing residual content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am parsing an xml successfuly using NSURLRequest and when connectionDidFinishLoading, xmlParser does the job. Problem is that if I modify remote xml file and fire again the connection, received data is the old one until I will fire it again random number of times until is finally been updated! It happens on device and also on simulator but funny issue is that on simulator, when there is no connection, sometimes acts as described before, with residual contents and console debugging messages as if connection exists... If code could help please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of your default cache policy in `NSURLConnection`. Check [`NSURLConnections`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) docs or just add this in your `NSURLRequest` creation.

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                            timeoutInterval:30];
```

The `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` might be the key for your issue.

Comment: this issue was driving me crazy... That's it, working! I appreciate so much your help!